# StringBuilder number of characters written per line

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, maxlength

Hello I've created some `C#` code that is writing to a .txt file using a `StringBuilder` `object`, everything seems OK, but the problem is that I need exactly 200 characters for each line.  For example, when the program sets a string variable value of 10 characters in a line (this value varies in the number characters), that line must contain 190 blank spaces.  This is an example of the code that I have:

```
if (File.Exists(DLFile))
{
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(DLFile))
    {
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      stringBuilder.Append("001" + partNumber + " ").AppendLine(); 
      String innerString = stringBuilder.ToString();
      sw.WriteLine(innerString);
      sw.Close();
    }
}
```

There is a string `variable` named 'partNumber' that varies in length.  Sometimes the length can be 15 or 14 or 10, but the sum of this length and the blank spaces may be 200 (exact quantity).  Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is there a reason that you use a `StringBuilder` and do not write to the stream directly?

Comment: oooh no reason in specific only for perform good programming practice

Comment: Please just make sure that this is not common misunderstanding. One shouldn't replace all string concatenations by a `StringBuilder` just to "improve performance". Doing so is usually only useful inside a loop body, i.e. when we talk about hundreds or thousands of concatenations. In your example you even already have access to a stream, so it is even more efficient not to concatenate your strings at all and write to the stream directly.

Answer (score 9):

Just use `PadRight` (Or `PadLeft` if appropriate) as it's designed to do exactly this.

```
sw.WriteLine(("001" + partNumber).PadRight(200));
```

Comment: this tool can give me this length result?

001 + partNumber + padRight(200) = 200

Comment: @MarcoSomoza You can always run it and find out for yourself.  You may also want to look up the documentation on the method to be more clear about what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Just take a look at the [String.format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method, and specify the format to achieve this.

In your case, it means doing something like:

```
string line = String.Format("{0,-200}", input);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about simply calculating and then [using this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxyxbz2e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?:

```
...

var h = "001" + partNumber;
stringBuilder.Append( h );

stringBuilder.Append( ' ', 200 - h.Length );

...
```

To make it (a bit) more error-proof:

```
...

var h = "001" + partNumber;
stringBuilder.Append( h );

var a = 200 - h.Length;
if ( a > 0 )
{
    stringBuilder.Append( ' ', a );
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this string constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx) to repeat white-spaces:

```
int whiteSpacesLength = 200 - partNumber.Length; // assuming partNumber is never > 200
string whiteSpaces = new String(' ', whiteSpacesLength);
string innerString = partNumber + whiteSpaces;
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/JIWgA6)

( so i see no reason to use a `StringBuilder` here)

Answer (score 0):

use a defined string with 200 spaces and then do a substring as below

```
string space200 = "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ";
      if (File.Exists(DLFile))
      {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(DLFile))
        {
          StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          stringBuilder.Append("001").Append(partNumber).Append(space200.Substring(stringBuilder.ToString().Length, space200.Length - stringBuilder.ToString().Length)).AppendLine();

          String innerString = stringBuilder.ToString();
          sw.WriteLine(innerString);
          sw.Close();
        }
      }
```

Comment: prompted me an error: 

startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex